# problem with document.getElementById accessing HEAD id="head"

Tags: javascript

I am accessing head,

var head = document.getElementById("head");

Works with IE, not with Firefox..

Comment: FYI, "id" isn't a valid attribute for "head" in HTML 4.01, although it is in XHTML 1.0. (Just thought I'd mention it, though it's not worth offering as an answer - Randell has already given you the solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the attribute id is not allowed in this particular tag.

Comment: That is correct: `id` is not a valid attribute for the `<head>` tag in HTML.

Comment: Can you provide us with link where are listed tags which cannot have id ? I am interrested particurarly in FRAME tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head id="head">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  alert(document.getElementById("head"));
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

work fine in firefox. but if you script is in the header and is runned automaticcally it could not work as the header is not fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Firefox 3 with Firebug:

```
>>> document.getElementById('head')
<head id="head">
```

Are you sure your head element has an ID of head?